# How can i pass the data from one Component to another using a button with redux and react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

i am working on a Billing list project..... and whenever the user clicks on a button in the Item Page, the button should send one random item with the Fetched API to the second page which is the Billing page and it should match and display the information!

After fetching the data with Axios i managed to save it to the Redux store.... I tried to use props to send the data or display it but nothing works, it returns an error saying **TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined**  !.... What am i doing wrong ?

I Would really appreciate some feedback or any suggestions that would help me. Thanks!

**Here is my code for the Item page** :

```
    import React, { useEffect , useState} from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { getItems } from '../store/actions/itemsActions';
import {  Link } from "react-router-dom";




function Items ({ getItems, items }) {

  useEffect(() => {
    getItems()
  }, [])

  


  function getRandomElt(arrayLenght) {
    return  items.sort(() => Math.random() - Math.random()).find(() => true);
  }




  function handleClick(){

    items &&
    items.items &&
     items.items.map(item => {
      <React.Fragment key={item.id}>
        <h4>{item.title}</h4>
      </React.Fragment>
    })

    
  }



return (
  
    

    <div>

      <div className="image" style={{ display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",}}>
        <img
        src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZlqh.png"
        alt=""
      />
        </div>
       
      


        <div className="button" style={{
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}>
         
          <div className="item-preview" >
            {
              items &&
              items.items &&
              items.items.map((item) => (
                <div key={item.id}>
                  <h2>{item.title}</h2>
                  <h2>{item.price}</h2>
                </div>

              ))
            } 
              {/* /${items.id} */}
          <Link onClick={handleClick}  to={`/bills`}
          ><button className="btn btn-primary">Analyse Receipt</button>
      
          </Link>

          </div>
     
        </div>
        
        
    </div>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    items: state.items
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    getItems: () => dispatch(getItems())
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Items)
```

**Here is my Billing page Code**:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Bill.css'
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { getItems } from '../store/actions/itemsActions';

function BillList ({ getItems ,items}){

  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(1)
  const incrementCounter = () => setCounter(counter + 1);
  let decrementCounter = () => setCounter(counter - 1);
  if(counter<=0) {
    decrementCounter = () => setCounter(1);
  }

  const { id } = useParams();
  let Total = 0


  // increase the item number 
  function ButtonIncrement(props) {
  
    return (
      <button style={{ marginLeft: '.1rem', textAlign: 'left'}} onClick={props.onClickFunc}>
      +
      </button>
    )
 }

//  will decrement the item number  

 function ButtonDecrement(props) {
  
  return (
    <button style={{ marginLeft: '.1rem',textAlign: 'left'}} onClick={props.onClickFunc}>
    -
    </button>
  )
}

// will display the current number 

function Display(props) {
  return (
    <label style={{ marginLeft: '.5rem'}} >{props.message}</label>
  )
}


 

    return(

      <div className='bills'>
       <h1>Product id: {id}</h1>

          <div className='title' style={{textAlign:'center', 
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
          fontSize: 14,
        }}>
          <h1>Bakery</h1>
          <h1>Company Gbr</h1>
          <h1>Oranienburger Straße 120</h1>
          <h1>10119 Berlin</h1>
          </div>
          

          <div className="bills-container">
          <div>
      </div>
     
            {/* pass in the details  */}
            <div className="bill-number">
            {items &&
            items.items &&
             items.items.map(item => 
            <React.Fragment key={item.id}>
              <div className="bill-number">
              <h3 > <strong>Bill: </strong>{item.billNumber}</h3>
              </div>
               <div style={{flex: 1,textAlign: 'right'}} className="time-date">
               <h3> <strong>Time: </strong>{item.created_datetime}</h3>
               </div>
                ----------------------------------
                ----------------------------------
                ---------------------------------- 
                -------------------- 
               
                <div>
                <h3 > <Display message={counter}/>x <strong>Title: </strong>{item.title}</h3>
                <ButtonIncrement style={{flex: 1,textAlign: 'left'}} className="increase" onClickFunc={incrementCounter}/>
                <ButtonDecrement style={{flex: 1,textAlign: 'left'}} className="decrease" onClickFunc={decrementCounter}/>
                
             
                </div>
                <div style={{textAlign: 'right'}} >
                <h3> <strong>Price: </strong> {item.price}</h3>     
                </div>
                <div>
               <span>Total: </span>     
                </div>
     
                </React.Fragment>
        )}

            </div>
         
          </div>
          <div lassName="button"
          style={{textAlign:"center"}}>
            <Link to={{
            pathname:'/',
          }}>
            <button>
            Analyse Receipt
            </button>

          </Link>
      

          </div>

          

    </div>
    )
  }


const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    items: state.items
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    getItems: () => dispatch(getItems())
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(BillList)
```

**Action:**

```
    import { GET_ITEMS, ITEMS_ERROR  } from "../types";
    import axios from 'axios'
    
    
    export const getItems = () => async (dispatch) => {
    
        try{
            const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/bills/')
            dispatch({
                type: GET_ITEMS,
                payload: res.data
            })
            
        }
        catch(e){
            dispatch({
                type: ITEMS_ERROR,
                payload: console.log(e),
            })
           
        }
        
    
    
    }


**App.js:**


    function App({items}) {
    
      function ItemPost() {
        let { id } = useParams();
        return <div style={{ fontSize: "50px" }}>
                 Now showing post {id}
               </div>;
      }
    
      
      return (
        <Router>
        <div className="app">
            <main>
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Items}>
        
                </Route>
    
                <Route exact path="/bills/" component={BillList}>
                  <BillList items={items}/>
                   </Route>
    
                   <Route exact path="/bills/:id" component={BillList}>
                  <ItemPost/>
                   </Route>
    
                
    
    
              </Switch>
    
            </main>
          
       
        </div>
        </Router>
      );
    }
```

Action:

```
export const getItems = () => async (dispatch) => {


    try{
        const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/bills/`)
        dispatch({
            type: GET_ITEMS,
            payload: res.data
        })
        
    }
```

Comment: A better approach would be to make the fetch after you land on the billing page, and not before. If you need to pass some parameters to the billing page in order to make the request, pass it via query params.

Comment: @YoavKadosh Thanks for your reply, but i'm a bit lost  ....so i should fetch the API data on the billing page ? what if i wanna send this data from the home button to the billing page is it still going to work ?

Comment: Yes, you should fetch the data on the billing page. Say you want to use the same billing page to display different bills based on some bill ID - you should pass the ID using query or path params (as part of the URL) and then read the ID in the billing page and use that for fetching the data. That way you can share the url and users can see the bill without having to navigate from another page. Something like mycoolsite.com/bill/123456 (where 123456 is the bill ID)

Comment: I used the hook useParams in App.js and its working fine, but  when i used it in the Billing Page it didn't show me anything... from what i understood it should show me the id but it didn't? ... i tried to add  the **${items.id}** in my api to check if this could help, but it returned an error .. am i doing something wrong ?  i also updated my code in case you need to check out. Thanks again for your help !

Comment: The button you click on should redirect you to a URL with the billing ID in it. Then you should use `useParams` to read the ID from the URL. Here's an example: https://reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params

Comment: Okay now it sends me to the billing page whenever i enter the ID in the URL it but with no data , but with the button it shows **undefined**, am probably doing something wrong !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a state management tool like Redux for example.

After fetching the data with Axios save it to the Redux store. Doing that makes the data available to be used by another components.

Comment: hey, thanks for your help.. i managed to create the redux, but how do i send the data from the Home component to the other one ?  i tried to use the mapping but it returned an error that says "mapping isn't a function" ...i think i have to use mapping to loop through the array and then pass them to the Billing Page, right ?

Comment: You need to connect BillingPage with Redux Store.
Once you have the data inside the store you can connect another components to the store and use this data.
Check this link about how to connect and use redux state and actions: https://react-redux.js.org/tutorials/quick-start#use-redux-state-and-actions-in-react-components

Comment: Oh okay, you mean i have to use both **mapStateToProps** and **mapDispatchToProps** to connect the billing page with Redux store ? .. i already did that. Afterwards, i used this as an example to pass in the API data  <h3>title:{props.itemData.title}</h3> so i can display it in on the billing page  but nothing happened..do i need to do something else to make the props work ?

Comment: Could you update the question with the changes or put the code in some online editor (JSFiddle)?

Comment: Yes sure, i added the latest version !

Comment: I presume that getItems action is fetching the data and saving it in state inside state.items. Is that correct? If yes, now you can read this items from the state using props.items on BillingPage component.

Comment: Thank you so much !!! .... i managed to display the data on the billing page, by mapping through the array of items using items.{WhatEverTheItemIs} !  Thanks for the redux tip as well it made it much easier to pass the data between different components !

Comment: But how do i use the button to display these data on the billing page ?.... there's a hook called useParams() .. maybe this could work to pass the id in the url and then displaying it in the billing page, right ?